# Unable to create user roles Class 'Mage_Notificationmanager_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, user-roles

I have a weird problem when trying to create user roles. It gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Notificationmanager_Helper_Data' not found in /public/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

I don't see a module called notificationmanager. All I can find is a notificationmanager module from wyomind, but when I turn this off the error stays the same.

This is on line 547 in Mage.php:

```
public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

The config file of Wyomind:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Wyomind
 * @package    Wyomind_Notificationmanager
 * @license    http://Wyomind.com
 */
 --> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wyomind_Notificationmanager>
            <version>2.1.0</version> 
        </Wyomind_Notificationmanager> 
    </modules> 
    <default>
        <notificationmanager>
            <notificationmanager>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <action_required>1</action_required>
            </notificationmanager>
        </notificationmanager>
    </default>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <notificationmanager>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Wyomind_Notificationmanager</module>
                    <frontName>notificationmanager</frontName>
                </args>
            </notificationmanager>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <notificationmanager_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Wyomind_Notificationmanager</module>
                    <class>Wyomind_Notificationmanager_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </notificationmanager_setup>
            <notificationmanager_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </notificationmanager_write>
            <notificationmanager_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </notificationmanager_read>
        </resources>
        <models>
            <notificationmanager>
                <class>Wyomind_Notificationmanager_Model</class>
            </notificationmanager>
        </models>
        <events>
            <admin_session_user_login_success>
                <observers>
                    <wyomind_notificationmanager_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>notificationmanager/observer</class>
                        <method>observe</method>
                    </wyomind_notificationmanager_observer>
                </observers>
            </admin_session_user_login_success>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: provide config.xml file of Wyomind module

Comment: I added the config.xml to my question

Comment: provide this module `adminhtml.xml` file I pretty sure error is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN your `config.xml` file in `global` node add below code

```
<helpers>
     <notificationmanager><class>Wyomind_Notificationmanager_Helper</class></notificationmanager>
</helpers>
```

and check and let me know

Comment: @user3478148 your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Data.php inside 'Wyomind/Notificationmanager/Helper' module.

```
class Wyomind_Notificationmanager_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the Data.php was already there with the same code as you showed me. Do you have an alternative answer?